# Do I need synchronize method Scheduled method?

Tags: java, spring, synchronization, scheduled-tasks

I have a Spring schedulled tasks which calls the same private method.
Do I need to sync this method? Will I have the problem if shedulled tasks runned in the same time? Or will be better to extract it to the prototype component or separate schedulled classes or something else?

```
public class SomeScheduled {

private final RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher;
private final ErrorRegisterRepository errorRegisterRepository;

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/4 * * * ?")
public void runRetry4minute() {
    runRetry(Duration.of(4, ChronoUnit.MINUTES), 1);
}

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/11 * * * ?")
public void runRetry11minute() {
    runRetry(Duration.of(11, ChronoUnit.MINUTES), 2);
}

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/29 * * * ?")
public void runRetry29minute() {
    runRetry(Duration.of(29, ChronoUnit.MINUTES), 3);
}

private void runRetry(TemporalAmount time, int someField) {
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now().minus(time);
    Page<ErrorRegister> page;
    int pageNum = 0;
    do {
        page = errorRegisterRepository.findBySomeCriteriaAndUpdatedAtBefore(someField, dateTime, PageRequest.of(pageNum, 500)); // Spring Data Jpa

        page.get().forEach(errorRegister ->
                requestDispatcher.dispatch(errorRegister); // inside put to ThreadPoolTaskExecutor 
        pageNum++;
    } while (page.hasNext());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` used by the `@Scheduled` annotation is, according to [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#scheduling-task-namespace-scheduler), created with a single thread in the pool.

Assuming that you have not customised that thread pool then it's not possible for your `runRetry` method to be called by multiple threads at the same time.

If your `runRetry` method is not thread safe then you should guard it anyway rather than relying on current default behaviour.